# What's the name of that lightbox script that has this Apple look & feel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I believed jQuery had it, but now I see the lightbox of jQuery isn't the actual cool one.

I'm talking about this light box in particular: http://tapbots.com/software/convertbot/ (click on the play video button, and the lightbox appears).

They seem to use exactly the one I'm searching, but have modified some of the graphics. The original one has a black rounded button on the upper left with a fat white X inside. Googling for lightbox brings up lots of stuff from photography to weird and ugly lightboxes with CSS only. I want

Comment: Well, in my point of view, any modalbox script might do the trick, you just have to modify the CSS and maybe a bit of JS but no big deal. You just have to make an _effort_ ¬_¬

Comment: Yeah, well, there are many ways to waste your time. This is one of them. Why not use the correct script in the first place? Tweaking another one to look like the one that exists is not that efficient...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you linked is using [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) and the [FancyZoom](http://www.cabel.name/2008/02/fancyzoom-10.html) plugin, so if you're on jQuery you'll have to go with a close equivalent.

---

I *think* you're talking about [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) by the description, but I'm not 100% clear.

Not a centered one, but SimpleModal also has an OS X look and feel, [check it out here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/).

Comment: Almost...FancyBox looks pretty similar, but it doesn't zoom out from the image and back into it. It just appears and hits the eye with an hard punch. The cool one was zooming from the image that was clicked up to the max size, and then back to that image. Damn cool effect... I think FancyZoom does the trick! :) although it seems to not make the background black... Not sure if that's the original one. But looks good! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[fancybox?](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 1):

try this : http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/styling.html